# automatically make a new line when generate using gofpdf

Tags: go, fpdf

how automatically make a new line when generate using gofpdf, for example i want the output like this
[image]

but im stuck here,
the output is always like this
[image]

the question is how to create a new line without crashing into another list

and this is my code

```
pdf.SetFont("arial", "B", 12)
pdf.SetFont("Helvetica", "", fontXs)
pdf.Text(88, 129.9, "Prepared By")
prLeft := (120.1)
prRight := (544.20 - 2*10) / 4
pdf.SetX(prLeft)
pdf.SetY(prRight)
pdf.SetFont("Helvetica", "b", fontXs)
pdf.CellFormat(20, 4, "", "", 0, "b", false, 0, "")
pdf.CellFormat(40, 4, "Name", "1", 0, "b", false, 0, "")
pdf.CellFormat(41, 4, "Title", "1", 0, "b", false, 0, "")
pdf.CellFormat(43, 4, "Division", "1", 0, "b", false, 0, "")
pdf.CellFormat(40, 4, "Signature & Date", "1", 0, "b", false, 0, "")

for _, dataRev := range pdfData.Approval.ReviewedBy {
    pdf.SetFont("arial", "B", 12)
    pdf.SetFont("Helvetica", "", fontXs)
    pdf.Text(88, 148.1, "Reviewed By")
    asLeft := (220.1)
    asRight := (615.10 - 2*10) / 4
    pdf.SetX(asLeft)
    pdf.SetY(asRight)
    pdf.CellFormat(20, 12, "", "", 0, "", false, 0, "")
    pdf.CellFormat(40, 12, dataRev.Name, "1", 0, "", false, 0, "")
    pdf.CellFormat(41, 12, dataRev.Title, "1", 0, "", false, 0, "")
    pdf.CellFormat(43, 12, dataRev.Division, "1", 0, "", false, 0, "")
    pdf.CellFormat(40, 12, dataRev.SignatureDate, "1", 0, "", false, 0, "")
    
}
```

and pdfData.Approval.ReviewedBy is array or slice [] and more than one element

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pdf data pounded when data more than one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73188990/pdf-data-pounded-when-data-more-than-one)

Comment: b, still not work with that code